# Density of the discrete measure w.r.t. counting measure

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

For the discrete measure on $\Omega = \{1, \cdots , 6\}$ with $\mu(\{i\})=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{7}$, $i=1\cdots ,6$, I need to figure out its density with respect to the counting measure.

Thus far, just to see what would happen, I calculated all of the $\mu(\{i \})$s, and added them up, and got $\frac{9}{14}+\frac{11}{14}+\frac{13}{14}+\frac{15}{14}+\frac{17}{14}+\frac{19}{14}=\frac{84}{14}=6$, which is the number of points in $\Omega$.

Noel, in my notes, we have the yfollowing definition of a density function:

> For measure spaces $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mu)$ and $(\Omega , \mathcal{F}, \nu)$ if there is some nonnegative measurable function $\delta$ on $\Omega$ suchthat $$\nu(A)=\int_{A} \delta(\omega)d\mu \geq 0\,\text{for any}\, A\in\mathcal{F}$$
>   Then , the measure $\nu$ is said too have a density $\delta$ w.r.t.measure $\mu$.

My problem is is that I don't know how to put all of this together - the formula says I need an event $A$, but I don't have that here.

Could someone please help me figure out how to use what I have, coupled with this formula to find the density I'm looking for?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $\mu A = \sum_{\omega \in \Omega}  \mu \{ \omega \} 1_A (\omega) = \int_A \mu \{ \omega \} d |\cdot|(\omega)$.

Hence the density is $\omega \to \mu \{ \omega \}$.

Comment: what does $d|\cdot |$ mean? And what is meant by the notation $\omega \to \mu\{\omega\}$? I.e. What does the arrow mean?

Comment: $|\cdot|$ is the counting measure on $\mathbb{Z}$. The density is a function $\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: didn't realize I was trolling. Sorry.